# Where are set the permissions for Web Workers in Chromium code?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, web-worker

I am designing a website as an application with a lot of Javascript code. All the users have the same browser, which is currently Chromium.

While designing some parts of the website, I figure out that it would be great to use Web Workers. Though, the can't access the `window` object, required for some libraries (such as jQuery or Swipe) to work. 
As every user install the browser I choose, is it possible to change Chromium code to allow such access to the web workers? Then, they will run my custom chromium and web workers will work.

I dig into the chromium source code and found nothing about permissions of workers. :-( I also know that it's against the logic of the workers but as this specific website will be the only one displayed in this custom chromium, it should be fine.

Thanks a lot !

Clems4ever